# USB 3.0 port does not work on carbon x1 laptop

Tags: usb

I have carbon x1 second gen and the USB 3.0 port does not recognize any usb device. Where do I start troubleshooting this issue?

I use Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Can you give us the exact model of your computer?

Comment: ThinkPad X1 Carbon - 20A7CTO1WW (2nd Gen)

Comment: 3.16.0-31-generic #43

Answer (score -1):

make sure you have all the necessary packages installed correctly.

1. do a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
2. check for available packages that are ready to be installed
3. go to Software & Updates, and look what u have "to be installed" from main server
4. if none of above works... Then either your laptop does not support USB 3.0 or the necessary packages are not installed correctly

don't forget to provide more information about your laptop.

Comment: thanks! i'll try dist-upgrade. maybe upgrading to 15.04 will help as well.

Comment: I just upgrade to 15.04 (3.19.0-16-generic #16-Ubuntu SMP) and also enabled usb 3 in the BIOS but still can't use the mouse on the usb 3 port.